# VSCode Information

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I delete this information from VSCode?

I activated something because it didn't appear before.

VSCode Information

[image]

Comment: Did you add an extension?

Comment: Seems like SCM plugin. Check the root directory of your project, see if there are any `.git` `.svn` or similar directories and report back. If you dont know anything about those tools (GIT, SVN, etc) then you should be able to safely delete those directories and maybe that information about 'uncomitted changes' will be gone. Alternatively, check Extensions panel on the left side and see if there's any "source control/versioning" extensions like - git, svn - etc and try disabling those extensions.

Comment: You cannot delete that information (it exists regardless of VS Code displaying it). Do not delete any folders like @quetzalcoatl is saying, those are there for your source control system and would remove source control. If it was not displaying before, you either: 1. initialized a source control system in the folder or 2. added an extension such as Git Lens to VS Code.

Comment: That is one of the git extensions you have enabled.  I can't remember which: `git blame` perhpas.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had installed GitLens. I have already removed and resolved the issue.